# Use t-scaled function from metRology in fitdist

Tags: r

I am trying to use the t-scaled function from metRology in the function fitdist from the package fitdistrplus. However, I keep getting the error 'The  dt-scaled  function must be defined' even though I am running both of these packages.

I am not sure what to do now.

Any help will be much appreciated!

```
library(metRology)
library(fitdistrplus)

z = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

x = fitdist('z', "t-scaled", start = list(df = 3, mean = mean(z), sd = sd(z)) )
```

Comment: You could start by posting your code and creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can reproduce the error you have and offer any suggestions to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function is dt.scaled, so it must be named in the fitdist-fuction as "t.scaled" with point and not dash. Also remove the parenthesis for the z argument.

```
 library(metRology)
 library(fitdistrplus)

 z = rnorm(1000, mean = 0, sd = 1)

 x = fitdist(z, "t.scaled", start = list(df = 3, mean = mean(z), sd = sd(z)) )
 x
```